# Mapping a bidirectional One-to-Many Hibernate Entity with JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I am trying to map a bidirectional One-to-Many relationship in Hibernate. In the build logs I receive the error "repeated column in mapping for entity."

What is generating the error?

The entity source code is below. One has a compound primary key. I am using Lombok to generate getters and setters.

The relationship: Award (One) --> AwardReceived (Many)

**Award Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "awards")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class Award implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "award_id")
    private Long awardId;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "award")
    private Set<AwardReceived> awardsReceived;

    @Column(name = "award_type")
    private String awardType;

    @Column(name = "award")
    private String award;

    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

}
```

**AwardReceived Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "awards_received")
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class AwardReceived implements Serializable{

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonUnwrapped
    private AwardReceivedPk awardReceivedPk;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "award_id")
    private Award award;

    @Column(name = "award_name")
    private String awardName;

    @Column(name = "citation")
    private String citation;

}
```

**AwardReceivedPk**

```
@Embeddable
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@Data
public class AwardReceivedPk implements Serializable{

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "client_no")
    private String clientNo;

    @Column(name = "award_id")
    private Long awardId;

    @Column(name = "year")
    private Long year;

}
```

Comment: You are getting the error since award_id is used twice in the mapping,

Comment: @shankarsh15 So is the JoinColumn annotation a user defined column name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Award award;
```

instead of

```
@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "award_id")
private Award award;
```

Comment: That seems to have worked. I was under the (incorrect) impression that the JoinColumn annotation pointed to the relationship key in the joined table.

Comment: Right, but also it creates column in AwardReceived to process join condition. Please check your table structure, it should contain column in AwardReceived with id of Award. Hibernate should find itself what id column of Award.