# Spring ManyToMany Composite Key

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I created the following models:

"Vendor"
"PickupStation"

And both of them have a OneToMany Relationship to a composite Key
"PickupStationVendorDetails" which has an embedded Id "PickupStationVendorKey"

It works to save the "PickupStationVendorDetails" with the corresponding Vendor and PickupStation but when I want to fetch them from e.g the Vendor nothing is found.

**Vendor.java**

```
@Entity
public class Vendor {
  ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "vendor")
    private Set<PickupStationVendorDetails> pickupStations;
}
```

**PickupStation.java**

```
@Entity
public class PickupStation {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "pickupStation")
    private Set<PickupStationVendorDetails> vendors;
}
```

**PickupStationVendorDetails.java**

```
@Entity
public class PickupStationVendorDetails {
    @EmbeddedId
    private PickupStationVendorKey id;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("vendorId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "vendor_id")
    private Vendor vendor;

    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("pickupStationId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "pickup_station_id")
    private PickupStation pickupStation;
}
```

**PickupStationVendorKey.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class PickupStationVendorKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "vendor_id", columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID vendorId;

    @Column(name = "pickup_station_id")
    private Long pickupStationId;

    public PickupStationVendorKey() {
    }

    public PickupStationVendorKey(UUID vendorId, Long pickupStationId) {
        this.vendorId = vendorId;
        this.pickupStationId = pickupStationId;
    }
....
}
```

**How I persist the entities:**

At first I create the embeddedID and save the details via repository:

```
PickupStationVendorDetails pickupStationVendorDetails = new PickupStationVendorDetails();
        pickupStationVendorDetails.setVendor(vendor);
        pickupStationVendorDetails.setPickupStation(pickupStation);
        pickupStationVendorDetails.setDeliveryDays(relationship.getDeliveryDays());
        PickupStationVendorKey embeddedId = new PickupStationVendorKey(vendor.getId(),pickupStation.getId());
        pickupStationVendorDetails.setId(embeddedId);
        PickupStationVendorDetails d = pickupStationVendorDetailsRepository.save(pickupStationVendorDetails);
```

Afterwards I add them to the Set<> of the corresponding Entities and save them too.

```
       vendor.getPickupStations().add(d);
        pickupStation.getVendors().add(d);
        vendorService.save(vendor);
        pickupStationRepository.save(pickupStation);
```

And when I try to call `vendor.getPickupStations()` there seems to be no relationship.
Except I call `pickupStationVendorDetailsRepository.findAll()` the composite Key is correctly persisted and saved, and from there on I would be able to get the PickupStation and the Vendor. But that's not how it should work I guess.

Am I missing something?

Comment: can't you cascade from one entity, whichever you think is parent as per your modelling?

Comment: Even when I cascade from one entity, the other one must relate to the details too.

Comment: I am not sure if it is related to your issue but I gave some answer yesterday about many to many relation, can you please check once? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67090141/jpa-insert-bad-number-of-parameters-in-a-relation)

Comment: Thanks. Your Bi-Directional mapping approach seems to be the same as mine here, except I have two "parents". I need to make sure that I can get all Vendors from a PickupStation and all PickupStations by a Vendor. When I set one as a cascading parent this would not be possible.

Comment: I think, you can do that the same way as you do from one side, it should not make any difference. It would need additional getters in both parents to retrieve other parent using lazy loading. Same thing can be done from `PickupStation` side as well, assuming you follow the approach from vendor side.

Comment: I tried the parental cascade approach. Sadly not working.

Comment: Could be an issue with mapping then because I just tried from both parent in my example and it works fine.

Comment: Mapping Issue. I solved it with removing the @JoinColumn Annotation from `PickupStationVendorDetails.java`. According to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306445/mapping-a-bidirectional-one-to-many-hibernate-entity-with-jpa

Comment: Glad  it worked, because I was trying your example :)